# Keep values in cache windows 8 application metro

Tags: c#, caching, microsoft-metro

i consume a webservice that returns a liste of country{name, population, superficie, iscapital,etc..}.

I need to put this in cache in application metro to avoid to call the webservice each time.

How can i do this in windows 8??

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `LocalStorage`, which will help you persist objects within your application. Read this:
[Using Local Storage with C# and XAML in Windows 8 Metro Apps](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-local-storage-with-c-and-xaml-in-windows-8-metro-apps.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list/array where you can store these items. You should persist these when your app gets suspended.

Comment: Not an expert, but isn't the OP asking how to do this?